# Python: count the list of words except when certain words precede

Tags: python, nltk

I am not sure whether there is any other relative question or not. If so, please let me know... I have searched it, but I could not find any..

I would like to count the list of words, if certain words do not precede the word by three or fewer words.. 
Here is the example from [Count occurrences of a couple of specific words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498665/count-occurrences-of-a-couple-of-specific-words)

I would like to count words, "foo", "bar", "baz" except "no" precede the words by three or fewer words. In this case, one bar and foo could not be counted..

```
vocab = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
exception= ["no"]
s = "foo bar baz no bar quux foo bla bla"

wordcount = dict((x,0) for x in vocab)
for w in re.findall(r"\w+", s):
    if w in wordcount:
       wordcount[w] += 1
```

Please help me.. thank you so much in advance..

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
vocab = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
exception= ["no"]
s = "foo bar baz no bar quux foo bla bla"

wordcount = dict((x,0) for x in vocab)

words = s.split()

i = 0
while i < len(words):
    cur_word = words[i]
    if cur_word in exception:
        i += 4
    else:
        if cur_word in vocab: wordcount[cur_word] += 1
        i += 1

print wordcount  # {'baz': 1, 'foo': 1, 'bar': 1}
```

It's just taking advantage of the fact that if we encounter "no", we can skip the following 3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `no` along with the following three words with an empty string and then  count for the words in the resultant string.

```
>>> s = 'foo bar baz no bar quux foo bla bla'
>>> vocab = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
>>> exception= ["no"]
>>> wordcount = dict((x,0) for x in vocab)
>>> m = re.sub(r'(?:^|\s)no(\s+\S+){0,3}', '', s)
>>> for w in re.findall(r"\w+", m):
        if w in wordcount:
            wordcount[w] += 1


>>> wordcount
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 1, 'baz': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually can do this with Python's strings -- no regex required:

```
vocab = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
ex_list= ["no"]
s = "foo bar baz no bar quux foo bla bla"

words=s.split()
wordcount = dict((x,0) for x in vocab)
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if i>=3 and any(w in ex_list for w in words[i-3:i]):
        continue
    elif word in vocab:    
        wordcount[word]+=1
```

Since slices do not generate index errors, you can simplify the loop to:

```
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if word in vocab and not any(w in ex_list for w in words[i-3:i]):
        wordcount[word]+=1
```